# Scapy send packets speed up in Windows

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, networking, scapy

In Windows I need to send an NBNS name query packet (which uses UDP protocol), and I need to send 255 packets and get an answer for each. With Scapy it takes a year, so I wanted to know if there is a way to speed it up or maybe use sockets instead?

Comment: `Use sockets instead` How do you think Scapy sends packets ? Dark magic ? ;-) You’re probably using it wrong. For instance, let it handle loops: `sendp(..., count=255)`, or use the builtins packet generators

Comment: But how to use socket? How can I bulid the packet from zero and send it via sockets?

Answer (score 0):

You could use two threads, one that is sending packets using a `conf.L3socket()` socket from scapy and another thread that is receiving packets using `sniff()`.